# Dumb questions: strcat and char pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am usually not using pointer chars when working with strings but I usually think they are better in the sense that I can print the whole string without iterating each character.

Anyway since I don't use them I don't really know how these two interact. When running the following code the program crashes, so I've got no clue what to do since there's no error.

```
int main(){
char s[]="abcde";
char *p;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    strcat(p,s+i);
cout<<*p;
}
```

I tried representing both strings as pointers and it didn't change anything. It crashes only if I try to print the second array. I tried *p++=*s or something similar I've found on google but it still crashes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first parameter of [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) has to be a pointer to `char` array big enough to hold the resulting string (and it has to be a null-terminated string itself already). Since that isn't the case here (you have an uninitialized pointer `p`) you are invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: @UnholySheep I think this is an answer, rather than a comment :)

Comment: So how do I go about it? I tried initializing the *p char to '/0' and it didn't help either.

Comment: I'm honestly still somewhat confused what the `for` loop is supposed to achieve - if it would work it would result in a string like `"abcdebcdecdedee"` - is that really what you want?

Comment: This has nothing to do with strings or even pointers. You're straight up using an uninitialized variable. This is wrong no matter what.

Comment: *I usually think they are better in the sense that I can print the whole string without iterating each character.* That's completely wrong, what gives you that idea?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to do. I mean it's obvious why the code crashes, but unless you say what you want the code to do how can anyone fix it?

Comment: If all you're trying to do is print an array of chars then you can just `cout << s`. No need to concatenate it char-by-char into a separate string.

Comment: I mean, yeah, that strcat inside the loop is confusing as hell, I didn't give any thought as to why it is in a for loop, I just want to see how the function works with pointer to chars. This piece of code is just for figuring things, not meant to achieve another purpose. My initial purpose was to use an array of chars and with the use of a pointer char(figured that'd be best for this thing), tried to concatenate the last letter of array of chars to the newly created pointer char *p and I got a lot of errors so turned to a little function and see how am I supposed to that.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer p points nowhere, you need to reserve memory for the second array. For example,

```
char *p = new char [strlen(s) + 1];
```

Also **strcat** in a **for** loop is not the best way to copy a string. Try

```
strcpy(p, s);
```

(after allocating memory to p, of course).

Addition: If you need to use **strcat** instead of **strcpy**, you need to initialize string p with empty string, that is:

```
char *p = new char [strlen(s) + 1];
*p = '\0';
```

Comment: The usage of `strcat` inside the `for` loop does a lot more than just a single copy of the string (which is why I asked for clarification from OP what they are trying to do)

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that s was declared as []. Fixed

Comment: I was not trying to do anything with strcat in the loop, was just testing to see how that function work with pointers, happened to put it in a foor loop, no specific purpose.

Comment: Your calculation is wrong.  We need `len - strlen(s); char *p = new char [len * (len+1) / 2 + 1];` because the end of the string gets copied `len` times.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating memory to a pointer p. When you call strcat without allocating memory of course you will get segmentation fault since strcat will try to write to a memory pointer by the pointer p.

You don't need a for loop for concatenating strings. strcat function does full string copying to memory pointed by p.

If you want print whole string don't deference pointer p fi you want print the whole string, deferencing results in printing only the first character of a string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

int main(){
char s[]="abcde";
//Allocating memory to so that p points valid memory.
char concatenatedString[50] = "";
//Initializing pointer to allocated memory.
char *p = concatenatedString;
// for(unsigned int i = 0;i < strlen(s); i++) //Not required.
    strcat(p,s);
//Here don't dereference if you want to print whole string.
std::cout<<p;
}
```

Comment: So it's necessary to use an array of chars and then make the pointer point to that array of chars? Isn't there any other way, I am pretty sure I've seen a couple of tutorials in which there's just declaration of char pointers and they work just like array of chars, somehow, I never got that thing, that's why I am usually using array of chars instead.

Comment: No, They work as array as chars after they point valid allocated memory. Always to pointer should point to valid memory before passing to strcat().